# Axler. Linear Algebra Done Right. 3rd Edition, Exercises 3D, Problem 18

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

Below you find my attempt to solve the following exercise:

> Show that $V$ and $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F},V)$ are isomorphic vector spaces.

If $V$ were a finite-dimensional vector space, then I would be confident that my proof below (with minor changes) would be correct. However, $V$ can be infinite-dimensional in the exercise above. While I know that some results for finite-dimensional vector spaces remain true in the infinite-dimensional case, other results do not. For this reason, I am not 100% confident that my proof is correct. Could you help me see if there are any mistakes? If any, could you explain to me how to fix them?

*Proof.* Suppose $\{\alpha\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{F}$ and $\{v_\lambda|\lambda\in \Lambda\}$ is a basis of $V$, where $\Lambda$ is an indexing set (which can be uncountable). Let $T_\lambda:\mathbb{F}\to V$ be a linear map such that $T_\lambda(\alpha)=v_\lambda,$ where $\lambda\in \Lambda$. We will prove that the set $\{T_\lambda|\lambda\in \Lambda\}$ is a basis of $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F},V)$.

Let $\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\alpha_\lambda T_\lambda$ denote a *finite* linear combination of the $T_\lambda$'s.

**Linear independence:** If $\alpha_\lambda\in\mathbb{F}$ are scalars such that $\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\alpha_\lambda T_\lambda=0$, then
$$\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\alpha_\lambda T_\lambda(\alpha)=0\Rightarrow\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\alpha_\lambda v_\lambda=0\Rightarrow \alpha_\lambda=0.$$

**Linear span:** Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{F}$ and $T\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F},V)$ be arbitrary. Since $T(\alpha)\in V$, it follows that
$$T(\alpha)=\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\alpha_\lambda v_\lambda=\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\alpha_\lambda T_\lambda(\alpha)=\left(\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\alpha_\lambda T_\lambda\right)(\alpha)\Rightarrow T=\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\alpha_\lambda T_\lambda.$$

Let $\varphi:\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F},V)\to V$ be defined as
$$\varphi\left(\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\alpha_\lambda T_\lambda\right)=\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\alpha_\lambda v_\lambda.$$
We will prove that $\varphi$ is an isomorphism.

**Linearity:** Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{F}$ and $S,R\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F},V)$. Then
\begin{align}
\varphi(\alpha S+R)&=\varphi\left(\alpha\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\beta_\lambda T_\lambda+\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\gamma_\lambda T_\lambda\right)=\varphi\left(\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\left(\alpha\beta_\lambda+\gamma_\lambda\right) T_\lambda\right)\\
&=\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\left(\alpha\beta_\lambda+\gamma_\lambda\right)v_\lambda=\alpha\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\beta_\lambda v_\lambda+\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\gamma_\lambda v_\lambda=\alpha\varphi(S)+\varphi(R).
\end{align}
**Injectivity:** Suppose $S,R\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F},V)$. Then
$$\varphi(S)=\varphi(R)\Rightarrow\varphi\left(\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\beta_\lambda T_\lambda\right)=\varphi\left(\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\gamma_\lambda T_\lambda\right)\Rightarrow\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\beta_\lambda v_\lambda=\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\gamma_\lambda v_\lambda\Rightarrow\beta_\lambda=\gamma_\lambda.$$
Therefore, $S=R$.

**Surjectivity:** Consider an arbitrary $v\in V$ such that $v=\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\alpha_\lambda v_\lambda$. Choose $T=\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\alpha_\lambda T_\lambda$. Then $T\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F},V)$ and
$$\varphi(T)=\varphi\left(\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\alpha_\lambda T_\lambda\right)=\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\alpha_\lambda v_\lambda=v.$$

Comment: I do not see mistakes, but this is a very complicated argument. This is one of the places where thinking in bases is counterproductive. Think, can you express $\varphi(T)$ and $\varphi^{-1}(v)$ without choosing any basis?

Comment: @VladimirLysikov Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately, I am not able to define an isomorphism $\varphi:\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F},V)\to V$ without choosing a basis.

Comment: You can define the mapping $\psi$ from $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F},V)$ to $V$ by $\psi(T)=T1.$ Should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using notation from OP, given $v\in V$ we can define a map $T_v\colon\mathbb{F}\to V$ as $T_v(a)=a{\cdot} v$.

The map $T_v\colon\mathbb{F}\to V$ is linear i.e., $T_v\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F},V)$ and we can consider the map $\psi : V\to\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F},V)$ defined as  \begin{gather}
\psi : V\to\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F},V)\\
\psi(v)=T_v
\end{gather}
The map $\psi$ is linear.

The one-dimensional vector space $\mathbb{F}$ is a field, hence it is provided with **the** canonical basis $\{1\}$.
Let us define the map $\phi\colon\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F},V)\to V$ as $\phi(T)=T(1)$, the map $\phi$ is linear too.

The maps $\psi$ and $\phi$ are inverse of each other, i.e. $\psi\circ\phi=\operatorname{Id}_{\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F},V)}$ and $\phi\circ\psi=\operatorname{Id}_{V}$.

It remains to prove the preceding claims, which should be standard. For the sake of example: $\psi\circ\phi(T)=\psi(T(1))=T_{T(1)}$, let us calculate $T_{T(1)}(a)=a{\cdot}T(1)=T(a1)=T(a)$ $\forall a\in\mathbb{F}$ i.e., $T\equiv T_{T(1)}$.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed proof. Could you please tell me if my proof given above is correct?

Comment: In my opinion your proof is correct and self consistent, and as a byproduct you got an explicit representation of a basis of $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F},V)$. 
I'll point out just a few remarks (mostly notational) in a following comment.

Comment: In the **linearity** section I'd use a different symbol for $\alpha\in\mathbb{F}$ since it is used for the (fixed) basis of $\mathbb{F}$. In the first and second sum I'd replace $\lambda\in\Lambda$
with $\lambda\in\Lambda'$ and $\lambda\in\Lambda''$,  in the third sum with $\lambda\in\Lambda'\cup\Lambda''$
where $\Lambda'$ and $\Lambda''$ are finite subsets of $\Lambda$;  and accordingly in the rest of the formula (the same for the **injectivity** section). **Injectivity** section: I'd use (if already proved in the book) that for $f$ linear, $f$ is injective $\iff$ $\ker{f}=0$.